# Take backup of USB drive to android

Tags: android, bash, shell, apk, backup

I want to be able to automatically backup USB data to android device whenever I plug it in. The android device is my own. I am comfortable in installing third party apps. I just want to automate this process. Each time I have to do it manually.

I have tried running scripts through termux. But Termux isn't able to access files located in USB device.

Comment: So you want to develop your own app that performs this synchronization?